# Kentico transformation with an asp:placeholder

Tags: kentico

I'm trying to set the visible="" based of of localization. My plan is two asp:placeholders, one for en-ca, the other for fr-ca. This is on my .masterpage, not a transformation.

I have some csm:link blocks, that i need the French aliased URL rather than the hard coded EN ones i currently have.

Comment: So what is your issue? visibility macro?

Answer (score 2):

Per the [Kentico documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Creating+transformations+for+documents) you just create a new transformation with the local at the end of the transformation name.  There's no need for a placeholder at all. For instance

Default transformation `cms.news.detail`
French transformation `cms.news.detail_fr-ca`

Answer (score 0):

Mark, have you looked at [conditional layout](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Editing+page+layouts#Editingpagelayouts-Creatingconditionallayouts)? I believe this is something that would work in your case.

Comment: Never mind - looks like it is not applicable for cultures, sorry

Comment: An other option is a conditional statement in the code behind and adjust the the LinkUrl of the cms:Link.

Comment: Are those internal link? Doesn't Kentico resolve them based on current culture?

Comment: not when the link is hardcoded in the cms:link. This was all fine until someone decided they didn't want the culture as a query string.

Comment: I'd consider implementation of a custom macro, so you could use everywhere across the site.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use an asp:placeholder, I figured out the following for the code behind:

```html
            // set culture based items
            // get first two characters of current culture, either en or fr
            string currentCultureCode = CMS.DocumentEngine.DocumentContext.CurrentDocument.DocumentCulture.Substring(0, 2);          


            if (currentCultureCode.Equals("fr"))
            {
                // set french logo
                mainLogo.ImageUrl = "mark.aspx";
                // set Ask US to FR URL
                AskUs.LinkUrl = "~/demandez-nous.aspx";
                CEODirect.LinkUrl = "~/president-en-direct.aspx";
                Events.LinkUrl = "~/evenements.aspx";
            }
```

For French, i'm asjudsting the logo image URL (i will when i have it), and i'm also adjusting LinkURLs.

Seems to be working fine so far.